# Get the average every 10 steps in a vector in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of values:

```
[1]   0  0  4  1  0  0 -1  1  1  0 -1  0  0 -2  0  0
[17]  1  2  0  2  0  1  1  1  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0
[33]  0  2  0  4 -2  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0 -1 -2  2  0
[49] -1  0 -1  0  3  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0  1 -3  0 -1
[65]  0 -1  0  1  1  0  1 -2  1  1  0  0 -1 -2  0  0
[81]  0  2  0  0  1  1  0  0  0 -1 -2  0 -1 -1 -1 -1
[97]  1  1  0  1
```

I would like to get the average every 10 steps (the average of the previous 10 numbers at that point), and thus produce a new vector with these averages. Since there are 100 values in the original vector this would give a new vector of length 10 (the 10 averages).

I know I can get access to the number at each 10th point using:

```
result <- my_vector[seq(1, length(my_vector), 10)]
```

But I need the average of the 10 previous points at that step, not just the number itself.

Comment: `rowMeans(matrix(x, ncol=10, byrow=TRUE))`

Comment: Or even just `colMeans(matrix(x, ncol = 10))`

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks guys,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
colMeans(matrix(x, 10))
[1]  0.4  0.7  0.8  0.2  0.0  0.4 -0.4 -0.4 -0.7  0.1
```

We turn the vector into a matrix with the dimensions matching your desired length and use `colMeans` to find the mean of each group. We could have also used `rowMeans`, but since the matrix is populated column-wise by default we would have to add another argument `byrow=TRUE` and potentially hurt ourselves with all of the extra typing.

We can test our answer by explicitly finding the mean of a few of the subsetted vectors.

```
#Test
mean(x[1:10])
[1] 0.4
mean(x[11:20])
[1] 0.7
```

**Data**

```
x <- c(0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, -1, 2, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 
2, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, -2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 
-2, 0, -2, -3, -2, -1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 
1, 1, 0, 1)
```